# Paperclip validation error on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, validation, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload excel files. There's a file that i can upload from my mac and windows using any browser. But when we try my co-worker's computer it says that file is not valid for uploading.

Is that even possible? I mean i thought validation process works on server. How can we get different results with the same file, same server, same browser?

Here's the validation code which i use on my model.

`has_attached_file :attachment
    validates_attachment_content_type :attachment,  content_type:['application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']`

What do u guys think about why its acting like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed the validation and worked like a charm!

```
validates_attachment_file_name :attachment, matches: [/\.xls/, /\.xlsx?$/, /\.csv?$/]
```